# How do URL shortener calculate the URL key? How do they work?

Tags: algorithm, url

How do [URL shortener's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_shortening) like [bit.ly](http://bit.ly/)  calculate a random key for each link? What algorithm would I need to know to create my own?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742013/how-to-code-a-url-shortener for some possible solutions

Comment: Did you not read the Techniques (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_shortening#Techniques) section? Is there something there that you don't understand? See Jeff's blogpost too: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/08/url-shortening-hashes-in-practice.html

Comment: @dirkgently That post to Jeff's blog should be an answer. Good info and I'm reading it now...

Comment: @ChrisF you answered the question with that link.

Comment: In that case this is a duplicate - I wasn't 100% sure which is why I didn't vote to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far I found the code from http://briancray.com/2009/08/26/free-php-url-shortener-script/

```
function getShortenedURLFromID ($integer, $base = ALLOWED_CHARS)
{
    $length = strlen($base);
    while($integer > $length - 1)
    {
        $out = $base[fmod($integer, $length)] . $out;
        $integer = floor( $integer / $length );
    }
    return $base[$integer] . $out;
}
```

and the more complex answer by [Marcel J.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742013/how-to-code-a-url-shortener/742047#742047) mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

I think they **DON'T** random a new key and checks if exists in database, because it its slower than just use a sequencial number and apply some <strike>criptography</strike> algoritm to convert sequencial id to a UNIQUE string.

Ex:

```
idUrl = 1003;
urlCode = doSomething(idUrl); // 161Llz
```

URL to use:
http://bit.ly/161Llz

Tks: mykhal and nick johnson

Comment: .. and then they hope there would be no collision :)

Comment: Cryptography has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe they store it in the database and just give you an link id. When you query this key they look in their database and forward you to the stored real link. To encode the id something like [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) (or similar) might be used.

Comment: well obviously he knew that since that's what he linked to

Comment: linking to the English version would've been nice though

Answer (score 0):

They most likely store it in a database and just generate the key randomly. I assume this because you can make your own key, and if they just decoded it you wouldn't be able to choose it yourself.

As for how to do it, you could just create a database in mySQL and have it hold the key and full site. Just search it for the key and then redirect the user to the full site.

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to store the key - my question is how do they "calculate a random key for each link?"

Comment: There's lots of ways. They may just do something as simple as come up with a few random numbers, and then assign a letter for each number and stick them all together. The fact that they use a database to store and look them up means they can use any method they wish, and that their algorithm doesn't have to take into account the actual URL