# Get Request URL Capability

Tags: get

I recently began working with JavaScript and am looking at various get and post requests one can send to a server.

For get, as far as I know, all of the information of the query is contained in the URL that the user triggers. On the server side this has to be dissected to retrieve the necessary parameters.

I was just wondering how larger and more detailed requests are handled with this get method? For instance what if I had millions and millions of parameters that make up my whole request? Would they all be jumbled into the URL? Is there a limit as to the number of unique URLs one can have? I read this post:

[How do URL shorteners guarantee unique URLs when they don't expire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326598/how-do-url-shorteners-guarantee-unique-urls-when-they-dont-expire)

I would really like some more input.

Thank You!