# Will this obfuscation algorithm for a URL shortener work?

Tags: algorithm, url, obfuscation, url-shortener, base62

DISCLAIMER: I am not asking how to make a URL shortener (I have already implemented the "bijective function" answer found [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742013/how-to-code-a-url-shortener/742047#742047) that uses a base-62 encoded string). Instead, I want to expand this implementation to obfuscate the generated string so that it is both:

**A) not an easily guessable sequence**, and

**B) still bijective.**

You can easily randomize your base-62 character set, but the problem is that it still increments like any other number in any other base. For example, one possible incremental progression might be `{aX9fgE, aX9fg3, aX9fgf, aX9fgR, … ,}`

I have come up with an obfuscation technique that I am pleased with in terms of requirement **A)**, but I'm only partially sure that it satisfies **B)**. The idea is this:

The only thing that is guaranteed to change in the incremental approach is the "1's place" (I'll use decimal terminology for practicality reasons). In the sample progression I gave earlier, that would be `{E, 3, f, R, …}`. So if each character in the base-62 set had its own unique offset number (say, its distance from the "zero character"), then you could apply the offset of the "1's place" character to the rest of the string.

For instance, let's assume a base-5 set with characters `{A, f, 9, p, Z, 3}` (in ascending order from 0 to 5). Each one would then have a unique offset of 0 to 5 respectively. Counting would look like `{A, f, 9, p, Z, 3, fA, ff, f9, fp, …}` and so on. So the algorithm, when given a value of `fZ3p`, would look at the `p` and, having an offset of +3, would permute the string into `Zf9p` (assuming the base-5 set is a circular array). The next incremental number would be `fZ3Z`, and with `Z`'s offset being +4, the algorithm returns `39pZ`. These permutated results would be handed off to the user as his/her "unique URL", who would never see the *actual* base-62 encoded string.

This approach certainly seems reversible; just look at the last character, and perform the same permutation with the negative offset. And I'm thinking that for this reason, it has to still be bijective. But I don't know if this is *necessarily* true? Are there any edge/corner cases I'm not considering?

**EDIT :** My intentions are more heavily weighed towards the length of the shortened-URL rather than the security of the pattern. I realize there are plenty of solutions involving cryptographic functions, block ciphers, etc. But I would like to emphasize that I am *not* asking the best way to achieve **A)**, but rather, "*is my offset-approach satisfying **B)***".

Any holes you can find would be appreciated.

Comment: Security via obfuscation is not security...at all...

Comment: What's your goal in obfuscation? Since your ID space is dense, people will still be able to guess other URLs, and it probably won't matter to them if it's the URL generated immediately before or after your one.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't entirely clear on my intentions with obfuscation. Gerrat, I agree there is no _real_ security, but that's because I don't see a _real_ threat to necessitate it? Someone please correct me if I'm wrong, but is there even a vulnerability if the sequence is discovered? (I guess you could crawl each URL, but what does that gain you?) Rather, I was just looking for a deterrent. Moreover, I feel like readability can suffer if, for example, someone shortens 3 URLs in succession and is given 3 _very_ similar looking results. Maybe that's a trivial concern? Is obfuscation even necessary?

Answer (score 2):

If you honestly want them to be hard to guess, keep it simple.

Start with a normal encryption algorithm running in counter mode. When you get a URL to shorten, increment your counter, encrypt it, convert the result to something using printable characters (e.g., base 64) and put the original URL and the shortened version into your table so you can get the original URL from the shortened version when needed.

The only real question at that point is what encryption algorithm to use. That, in turn, depends on your threat model. I don't see exactly what you gain by making shortened URLs hard to guess, so I'm a bit uncertain about the threat model.

If you want to make it mildly difficult to guess, you could use something like a 40-bit version of RC4. This is pretty easy to break, but enough to keep most people from bothering.

If you want a bit more security, you could step up to DES. That's been broken, but even at this late date breaking it is *quite* a bit of work.

If you want more security than that, you can use AES.

Note that as you increase the security, the shortened URL gets longer though. RC4-40 starts out with 5 bytes, DES 7 bytes, and AES with 32 bytes. Depending on how you convert to printable text, that's going to expand at least a little.

Comment: I presume you mean "threat model", not "thread model" - that's something else entirely. :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Please see the comment I posted to Nemo's answer, as it applies here as well.

Comment: If you're going to put *both* the original URL and the shortened version into the table, wouldn't it be even simpler to pull some fixed number of bytes bytes from /dev/random and encode that into printable characters as the short URL ?

Comment: @DavidCary: Not really (at least IMO)--in that case, you'd have to check your proposed URL against all your existing ones to ensure it's unique. Encryption in counter mode assures against duplicates automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the [Luby-Rackoff construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luby-Rackoff_construction#Theoretical_work) (see also [here](http://crypto.cs.uiuc.edu/wiki/index.php/Luby-Rackoff_construction)), which is a way to generate a pseudo-random permutation from a pseudo-random function.

You just have to pick a "round function" F.  F must take as input a key K and a block of bits half the size of what you are encoding.  F must produce as output a block of bits also half the size of whatever you are encoding.

Then you just run the Luby-Rackoff construction (aka. "Feistel network") for four rounds, each round using a different K.

The construction guarantees that the result is a bijective map, and it will be hard to invert provided that F is hard to invert.

Comment: Related: http://blog.notdot.net/2007/9/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Part-2-Secure-permutations-with-block-ciphers (Full disclosure: I wrote that). I wish I'd known it was a Luby-Rackoff construction when I did.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I considered using a model based on cryptographic functions, but concluded that the tradeoff between security and shortened-URL-length wasn't worth it. In the incremental base-62 approach, you can have 62^n possible URLs of length n. That means over 238k at just 3 chars, and almost 15mil with 4 chars. If you read the comment I posted on my question, I explain more clearly my intentions, and why security isn't my highest priority. I apologize for not making this more evident in my initial inquiry. That being said, what do you think of my offset approach?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to solve the same problem (in php) and ended up with those functions:

- [hashing the row id with a kind of feistel algo](https://gist.github.com/baldurrensch/3710618)
- [applying a bijective function to compress the integer](http://www.flickr.com/groups/api/discuss/72157616713786392/)

So for the A): it's not easily guessable (to me) as you cant increment a string to get the next record without an algo

And for the B): for what I understand it's 100% bijective.

Thanks to @Nemo for naming the feistel network, which lead me to the first function i have linked to.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to avoid people crawling the URLs, I think Nick Johnson has the right idea, that you need to make sure your URL space is not dense.

Here's a simple idea: take your URL, and prepend a few random characters to it. Then run it through a compression algorithm -- I'd try range encoding (you can probably specify the basis if you find a good library). This should be decompressible to the original form, and should both impact locality and make the encoded space more sparse.

That said, I imagine nearly all URL shorteners out there keep a hash table with state on the server side. How else are you going to losslessly compress a hundred-character URL into 5 or 6 characters?