# Implementing URL shortener logic in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, url-shortener

As a result of finding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742013/how-to-code-a-url-shortener) interesting question, I decided to write an example in JavaScript which implemented the logic and contribute it back to the question. The problem is that I'm having some issues implementing the logic. I can speak Ruby which is what I'm basing my implementation on, but I'm having an issue with an endless while loop which I'm having trouble sorting out.

I have the whole implementation up on js.do.it here: http://jsdo.it/rfkrocktk/k9Jq

```
function encode(i) {
   if (i == 0) return DICTIONARY[0];

   var result = '';
   var base = DICTIONARY.length;

   while (i > 0) {
       result += DICTIONARY[i % base];
       i = i / base;
   }

   result = result.reverse();
   return result;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `/` probably isn't doing what you expect.  `1/2 => 0.5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript uses floating point math by default.  Use `i = Math.floor(i /  base);`

Comment: That was definitely one of the issues, fixed it.