# Improving on Url Shortner Performance?

Tags: url, url-shortener

[I've looked around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742013/how-to-code-a-url-shortener) and seen the way to create your own url shortener/mapping is by using an auto increment PK, convert it to base62 to use as the short_key, and then use the key to access the long_url value on queries. If I could set the short_code to be the PK, I would essentially gain a free index.

Is there a conversion that can shorten a string url (eg www.news.google.com#top) to a <6 character alphanumeric short_code that will be reliably unique?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can make the shortcode reference your PK auto increment index:
[Github: ShortURL](https://github.com/delight-im/ShortURL/blob/master/C%23/ShortURL.cs)