# Unique string (id) from two parameters

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've been reading a lot about how to generate a unique id, using hash, sha, md5, and things like that.

I need to generate a unique id for a unique url using two parameters, so I can't use an md5 hash, or sha because those are way too long, and the url will be really big.

I like the way youtube identifies each video, anybody knows how this can be done? anything to read?

Thanks!

Comment: what is the type of the two parameters? what is the range (if params are numbers)

Comment: You don't tell us what your requirements are. Is uniqueness all you need? What is the nature of your parameters? Could you just concatenate them? Digests like MD5, SHA-family, etc., also provide protection against reversing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to code a URL shortener?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742013/how-to-code-a-url-shortener)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should read this thread [How to code a URL shortener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742013/how-to-code-a-url-shortener) it answer your question exactly