# Encode id to numbers and letters?

Tags: ruby

I want to encode an id to unique strings containing numbers and uppercase letters, like this:

```
40 => A5TY8
```

but

```
41 => Y7HEG
```

Where the output for `41` is completely different from `40`'s `A5TY9`.

How to do this?

Comment: How many ID numbers are you anticipating? Is it feasible to make a list just once, or do you need to be able to generate on the fly?

Comment: I want generate it on the fly. I want 2 functions encode and decode, so it can't be md5 or sha. It can be billions of ids so generating once and using it - it's not the solution.

Comment: Do they have to be unique and short? If so you need some kind of look-up table.

Comment: Not necessarily short. Unique, decodeable

Comment: http://uuidtools.rubyforge.org/

Comment: Sounds similar to this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742013/how-to-code-a-url-shortener

Comment: I tried this before but outputs are similar. JRE, JRF...

Comment: @MichałK. Try to randomize the alphabet and test again.

Comment: @Pafjo I did it. And I have: TA => 494
T0 => 495
TD => 496
TW => 497
T3 => 498
T9 => 499

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to tell you all about digests.. but seeing your comment I think you want something like this

https://github.com/namick/obfuscate_id

or better yet a more generic

https://github.com/patdeegan/integer-obfuscator

you can also encode it with Base64 which is reverisble

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html

note that you might want to use `urlsafe_encode64` so you won't have /n and stuff in there

so you can do something like

```
require "base64"

original = 41

converted = Base64.urlsafe_encode64("41")
converted_for_display = converted.tr('^A-Za-z0-9', '')
# => "NDE"

reversed = Base64.urlsafe_decode64(converted)
```

you can also encrypt the number which should make it unique and reversible, but slower and with more hassle but you can pick whatever key you want

Comment: Thank you, but solution numbers with base are similar, NDE, NDA. The most interesting is using integer-obfuscator and then use base.

Comment: ALPHABET =   "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".split("").shuffle.join
def bijective_encode(i)
  return ALPHABET[0] if i == 0
  s = ''
  base = ALPHABET.length
  while i > 0
    s << ALPHABET[i.modulo(base)]
    i /= base
  end
  s.reverse
end

def bijective_decode(s)
  i = 0
  base = ALPHABET.length
  s.each_char { |c| i = i * base + ALPHABET.index(c) }
  i
end

$salt = 1369136
def decode(id)
  (bijective_decode(id) >> 18) - $salt
end
def encode(id)
  bijective_encode((id+$salt) << 18)
end I can't "Answer your question" but this is the best solution for me.