# Convert ugly urls to user friendly urls

Tags: .htaccess

In my website there are lot of ugly URLs and now I need to rewrite them to nice user friendly URLs.

These are some of ugly URLs from my website :

```
http://www.mydomain.com/profiles/tutors/index.php?code=1285&name=Ricky+Pointing
http://www.mydomain.com/profiles/centers/index.php?code=2285&name=City+&+Gills
http://www.mydomain.com/about.php
http://www.mydomain.com/contact.php.... and much more
```

So I am looking for nice user friendly solution to above ugly URLs, something like this :

```
http://www.mydomain.com/tutors/Ricky_Pointing.html
http://www.mydomain.com/centers/City_&_Gills.html
http://www.mydomain.com/about.html
http://www.mydomain.com/contact.html
```

I tried it something similar this in my .htaccess file..

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /profiles/tutors/index.php\?code=([0-9]+)&name=([^&]+)&?([^\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^profiles/tutors/index\.php /%1/%2/?%3 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(.+)/$ /profiles/tutors/index.php?code=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]
```

But still no luck. 
Can anybody help me to do this?
Thank you.

Comment: You always can use url shortners. You can find more info from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742013/how-to-code-a-url-shortener

Comment: I know, I didn't mean to convert it to something like http://www.mydomain.com/dgGc32G. I meant something like http://www.mydomain.com/Ricky_Pointing. You are right, it could be done by adding another column to the database and store the shortened url. It doesn't need an actual url shortner.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be overcomplicating it with `RewriteCond`s and such. You'll probably have rules like this:

```
RewriteRule ^about\.html$ about.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contact\.html$ contact.php [L]
RewriteRule ^tutors/(.*)\.html$ /profiles/tutors/index.php?name=%1 [L]
RewriteRule ^centers/(.*)\.html$ /profiles/centers/index.php?name=%1 [L]
```

You'll then have to modify your PHP scripts to look up the appropriate thing with that name without relying on having the `code` present. It'll also have to deal with the presence of underscores as existed in the original URL.