# how to generate short, unique urls

Tags: url, short-url

I am trying to generate unique, short urls for items on my site. For example, a user might add an item and the resulting url would be something like:

```
http://example.com/item/abc
```

I was hoping for the unique identifier to be made up of 3 or 4 characters, where the characters are letters and numbers. I thought instead of randomly generating the strings and then making sure they are unique and haven't been used yet, I could generate them all ahead of time and store them in a database. Then when a user adds an item I could just select the next shortened url string from the database and assign it to that item. Is this a good way to solve this? Are there better ways? I thought it would make it simpler since they are already  generated. However, I could also see a potential race issue with two items being assigned the same identifying string, and I'm not sure if `LOCK TABLES` would be the best solution or not.

Also, without using `LOCK TABLES`, could something like this guarantee no race conditions in MySQL?

```
update ids set item_id=1 WHERE id=(SELECT id FROM ids WHERE item_id IS NULL LIMIT 1);
```

And then I could select the id for item that has id 1? During that query would no other query be able to claim it?

Comment: If you store your items in a database, they probably have some kind of id, right? Couldn't you generate a three or four character string from that id, like, `1` -> `aaa`, `2` -> `aab`, ... ?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742013/how-to-code-a-url-shortener

Comment: @PoByBolek, yes I could. I was just hoping for the string to be less predictable. Not necessarily in order.

Comment: Something like this might fit the bill: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196017/unique-random-numbers-in-o1

Comment: @Swapnil, thanks! That's a great resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone who finds this question later, I followed the process suggested in the link that @Swapnil suggested:

[How to code a URL shortener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742013/how-to-code-a-url-shortener)

There were some implementations listed there for various languages, but I am using perl and that wasn't listed there and I couldn't seem to find a perl one that already existed elsewhere. So if it helps anyone in the future, I wrote this perl module to help with url shortening:

[Short::URL](https://metacpan.org/pod/Short::URL)

Thanks to @Swapnil for pointing me to the right place.

Answer (score 1):

Just about your short urls question.

You can encode the url in a shorten representation.

In python you can hash the url and later encode it to b64, that will reduce the length and have a unique representation for the url

```
>>> import base64
>>> import md5
>>> url = '/item/abc'
>>> hash = md5.new(url).digest()[-4:] # get the hash for the url
>>> hash = _hash.replace('=','').replace('/','_')  # some cleaning
>>> print base64.b64encode(hash)
'CVKi2Q'
```