# Produce and resolve short file path

Tags: java, file, hash, path

I want a collision free hash value that is as short as possible. I want to use it as a pretty directory path to a file name.

- I want to build a directory tree that has an almost equal length path
  to any file in it.
- The files have binary content.
- Two files of identical content should produce identical file paths (I
  think that is what the hash should provide).
- Hash length should be minimal.
- Hash calculation time is NOT the top priority since the hash
  calculation is done once for each file.

My current solution:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;

String shortHash(){
  byte[] content = "sample".getBytes();
  byte[] hex = DigestUtils.md5(content);
  String filename = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(hex);
  return filename;
}
```

It produces the hash value *5e8ff9bf55ba3508199d22e984129be6* and a file name as *Xo_5v1W6NQgZnSLphBKb5g*

To store many files in a directory tree, I simply split the file name to produce a file path like this:

```
<basedir>/Xo/_5/v1W6NQgZnSLphBKb5g
```

How can I produce a shorter file path?

Comment: Well, for a start, instead of transforming the MD5 digested bytes to hex, then hex to base64, you could simply transform bytes to base64. That would make the result twice as short.

Comment: Please define *exactly* what you mean by "collision free" here.

Comment: @JBNizet Well, that's fine. I'll edit my solution.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm not aware of more conditions for the term "collision free". I want an 1:1 association from file name to content of the file. No or minimal duplicate files with the same content should exist. The use case is a file store where any file dropped produces a distinct file path.

Comment: So *either* you can't make the hash purely based on the content of the file - it would have to take account of existing files, *or* the hash must be able to be at least as long as the file (however large that is), by the pigeon-hole principle. In particular, your current solution is going to fail, as any fixed-size hash such as MD5 is bound to have collisions.

Comment: Of course, you could choose a hash which is *extremely unlikely* to have collisions, but that's not the same as collision-free.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorting things out is a good strategy to narrow possible solutions. Why is a [hashcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_code) not a solution? I thought hashes are made for mapping data of arbitrary size to fixed sized data. Could you elaborate a bit more on your statement or guide me to the concepts I need to understand?
May I have to be not so strict in the sense of _collision free_?

Comment: Hash codes are used for two distinct reasons: a) in hash tables and the like, to narrow down candidate matches for equality (typically of keys) very quickly, where collisions are *somewhat* rare but thoroughly expected due to the small hash code size (typically 32 bits) and b) in cryptography, where hash collisions are expected to be *extremely* rare, but are still not impossible. Cryptographic hashes are designed to make it incredibly difficult to deliberately achieve a collision. But fundamentally you *can't* map an arbitrary size of data down to a fixed size and guarantee no collisions.

Comment: If you want it to be somewhat less strict, e.g. "there is a miniscule chance of a hash collision" then pick a decent cryptographic hash (SHA-256 springs to mind) and use that. That's not "collision free" in the sense that there certainly will be *possible* collisions - it's just incredibly unlikely that you'll actually see them.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for clarification. So I have to accept collisions, even if extremely rare. That means two keys can produce the same hash code. I need a strategy on how to handle this case. But that is another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want a collision free hash value

A hash is never collision free, but you can choose a hash algorith which is *extremely unlikely* to have collisions, as Jon Skeet explained.

> How can I produce a shorter file path?

You need to distiguish two responsibilities.

1. The hash value for the file gives you fast collision detection.
2. Produce a short file path. Take a look at [alphabet conversion theory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/742047/2822745) and [Java UrlShortener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11424323/2822745) implementation.

To handle #2 you follow these steps:

**a)Convert**

1. Save real file path in database
2. You get a unique row ID for that
3. Convert row ID to short string with encode()
4. Use the short string as your short file path

**b)Resolve**

5. Decode the short file path to an integer ID with decode()
6. Look up real file path in database for given ID

Answer (score -1):

You can use a [Cyclic redundancy check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check), which generates a value based on the bytes of your content. This is the one I use in Java, which returns a long:

```
public static long crc64(byte[] data) {
    long crc = 0xffffffffffffffffL;
    for (int b : data) {
        int b2 = (int) (((crc >> 56) & 0xFF) ^ (b & 0xFF));
        crc = (crc << 8) & 0xffffffffffffffffL ^ CRC64_Table[b2];
    }
    return crc;
}
```

The `CRC64_Table` is too big to post it here, so I've uploaded it to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/eHpf8LuN).

EDIT: You can also use a 32 bit version, like this one: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/51data/CRC32.java.html

Comment: That's not going to be collision-free. (Nor is any other hash of an arbitrary quantity of data... I don't think the OP's question really makes sense - but a CRC isn't an answer to it.)

Comment: @Emd4600 Thanks for your suggestion. I'm sorry to say that it doesn't help with my goal. I do NOT need code for common algorithms, I can research that myself. But I would like to know which concepts would help me to find a solution.