# space effective storage of credit card information

Tags: credit-card, data-storage, bigdata

To make some background , suppose I am running a very famous booking site somewhat like "Booking.com".On my site .

Same as booking.com I do not charge user on booking conformation but hotel owner charges from the credit card information user has provided while booking .

Now, I am having a reliable channel from which , I am getting credit card information which are recently hot listed or blocked . I am getting a huge number of credit card data on daily basis.

If some customer tries to make booking with such credit card , I need to stop such booking .

I have a approach to partition my credit card table on basis of last 4 digits of Credit card , which will help me to increase speed . But I am worried about space usage also as I am receiving huge amount of data every day.

I would like to have some suggestions on how efficiently should I store credit card data that they are storage and speed effective .

P.S - Do not worry about credit card storage norms and security concerns .

Comment: Do you have an actual, measurable problem to solve here? Then it'd be helpful if you could share some numbers. It seems very hard to imagine storage problems with credit card numbers, even if you have half of mankind's credit cards. Also what platform/s is this on? (If this is a real problem, it might be better off on the database admin site, on which I notice you already have an account...)

Comment: I am getting roughly 500 such credit card data on every week. does it help ?

Comment: 500? That should seem like a joke for any serious DBMS. No?

Comment: ok,what If the number grows to 50000 ? I would like to know how to efficiently should I store them . And I have brought the question here because , I do not think of it as a database management issue . I am looking for something creative as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742013/how-to-code-a-url-shortener

Comment: Several million rows are also easy if your tables are properly indexed, etc. URL shorteners shorten URLs for the convenience of the humans using them, not to save storage space. I put it to you that once you have so many credit card records you have to *really* worry about database performance, your service will have grown so much that it has the resources to simply buy bigger servers - or implement smarter storage strategies if needed. No point worrying about it now.

Comment: How are you currently storing the numbers - datatype of the column ?