# Is there a way to shorten an array of string unique ids while still ensuring unique-ness?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, firebase-realtime-database, uniqueidentifier

I have an array of string unique ids from a Firebase database, one of which looks like this: `QXgZI3JB72Zf1qzeawIdxHSsPa62`

I want to print these ids to the user, but first I'd like to first shorten the ids to around 7 characters long minimum, but have it go over that length in case two shortened ids end up becoming equal. That way, if somebody wants to refer to a specific id, they can use the shortened version without accidentally referring to multiple things.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

---

To get a better idea of what I'm talking about, refer to the `git` command `git rev-parse` ([docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html)), which has the `--short` flag that cuts a commit hash to at least 7 characters long (but will allow it to be longer in case it's no longer unique):

> Instead of outputting the full SHA-1 values of object names try to abbreviate them to a shorter unique name.

Comment: Yes, there is a way to accomplish this (actually, many different ones). What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I was thinking of slicing each string of the array, checking for equality on all of them, then slicing the equal ones again. Before I do that though, I was just wondering if there was a name for what I'm trying to do and if there's a library that already does this a lot better than what I just described. (of course, unless the answer is so simple that it's preferable  to just do it myself.)

Comment: Do you want to ensure unicity forever (across multiple invocations), or just on a single page? Is there any reason you actually need to list IDs for the user, rather than have them click on a link or something similar?

Comment: @octopod I guess your search terms should include "unique prefix".

Comment: @jcaron: preferably, and yes, because it's actually a node.js process (apologies for mis-tagging) and the only way of referring to a _specific_ object in an Firebase array to my knowledge is knowing the entire identifier (unless I read it from the database into an array and refer to the objects by their index, but what if I change the order of it later?). Although, you do have a point once I do use them for a website, I should probably use links instead.

Comment: @octopod Your approach seems to be fine. Use a `Set` or `Map` for efficient lookup of the equal items. There are even more efficient approaches, but they tend to get complex; you shouldn't look into them until performance actually becomes an issue.

Comment: Sure it's "possible": just pretend you're a [Hash Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). Compute a shortened "hash" output of the input (using whatever means necessary, including truncation) - note that this is *not* a bijective function - and keep track of the shortened output. Keep doing this for all the inputs and, if there is an input for which there is a collision, apply a secondary function repeatedly to make the output unique.. Also note that the *ordering and data of the input* will determine the final results.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no safe method to shorthen unique ids after they are produced (CMIIAW).

The ids unqueness is assured by a central server, which guarantees for their uniqueness: in the case of a conflict, it will recalculate a different id, until it's unique.

If you shorten ids after they are emitted, you can't be 100% guaranteed they will be unique, if you do not want to replay server's job, keeping a database of ids...

As you said `git --short` prints a shortened version of commit ids, but *will allow it to be longer in case it's no longer unique* ...

Comment: In this case, safety's not an issue. These identifiers are simply referring to indexes of an array because the `.push()` function in Firebase doesn't assign it an array index, it assigns it a unique identifier (with after some work, doesn't really matter because `.forEach()` ensures array order anyway). The information inside isn't sensitive at all; anyone can see it.

Comment: I used 'safe' to mean '100% sure'... I did not imply anything about security... :-( Sorry, I'm not English native speaker...

Answer (score 0):

The thing that is missing from the question is whether you are willing to retain a lookup table, or if you are seeking a two-way encoding method where the long string is algorithmically encoded into a shorter string which can then be decoded into the original string.

If the latter is the case, then good luck and please post your answer here if/when you find it!

Otherwise, just make a hash of key/value pairs:

```
var dbKeyHash = { "xyz":"QXgZI3JB72Zf1qzeawIdxHSsPa62",
   ...
}
```

The key could be an incrementing number, or any other short but unique string. Going through your list of database keys, you could generate a short string at random, and if it's not already in the hash, use it, otherwise, generate another and continue.

Then, when a user references one of the short keys you display, you just look up the value in the hash:

```
var dbKey = dbKeyHash['xyz'] // QXgZI3JB72Zf1qzeawIdxHSsPa62
```

You might find something good on this thread as far as generating short strings: [How to code a URL shortener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742013/how-to-code-a-url-shortener)