# Adding custom URL support for my URL shortener

Tags: php, mysql, database, algorithm, url

I've built a URL shortener using the *Bijective Function* algorithm as stated in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742013/how-to-code-a-url-shortener). My database table has two columns; `ID` and `URL`. For every input URL, the `ID` is automatically incremented its value is converted to base62. This value forms the slug for the shortened link.

**Example:** If `ID` is `42` then its base62 form is `g` (may differ according to the alphabet set). So the shortened URL is `https://example.com/g`.

Now I'd like to add custom URL support where the user chooses a custom URL slug. I could create another table to store custom URLs and then check both tables for a matching slug. But this seems rather inefficient.

***Can anyone provide an efficient solution?***

P.S. I'm using PHP and MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the reverse mapping of the slug to the corresponding ID it would occupy if it was naturally generated, just keep this in mind:

Before increasing your ID variable you can make sure the entry it would increase to is not already populated by someone who entered a slug which corresponds to that ID, if that's the case just keep incrementing the ID column until you find a new unique value.