# Get short URL from long URL

Tags: url-shortener

I was just reading this question [How to code a URL shortener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742013/how-to-code-a-url-shortener) where the top answer focusses on getting an auto-incremented ID for the long URL and then has functions which creates a short URL from the ID and also a function which goes back to the ID from the short URL.

However, would this not mean that if you input the same long URL again to generate a short URL it would auto-increment to a new ID and therefore create a different short URL?

If you wanted to make sure it returned the same short URL I think this means on the database that is currently storing a big hash table with just 'id' to 'long url' you need another index hash table for the 'long url' to 'id'?

Is there a more efficient way of doing this rather than having to double the memory storage?

Answer (score 0):

I have an implementation for this, so basically I am generating a unique `UUID` for the specific URL as `key` and the actual url as `value`.

To make things more clear, here is the [Github Link](https://github.com/vmanikes/URL-Shortner/blob/master/URL_shortner.py)

In your front-end

> `<b><a href="{{***Value***}}">{{ **Key** }}</a></b>`

Comment: How is the unique UUID generated in your case? There still needs to be a way of getting UUID back again from the URL

Comment: I am using the `uuid` module of python to generate the UUID, here is the method `str(uuid.uuid3(uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS,url))[:7]`

Comment: As the UUID is being generated from a hash of the URL this means that the UUIDS will not always be unique doesn't it which is a problem

Comment: I am not hashing the URL, I am using the URL to generate a UUID which will be same all the time for the same URL

Comment: you are calling the function uuid3 which is implemented using a hash https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid3 so different URLs could potentially to be hashed to the same UUID

Comment: That is why I am using this name space `uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS`