# How to create a temp link for my website?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I want to create a simple URL-shortener and I want to create a link that looks like this - `http://mywebsite.com/<random_string>`. I already done all the steps with the database, but I don't know if I need to create a new HTML file with the random string as it's name, or I can do that in different ways.

Do URL-Shorteners creates a new page that automatically redirect users to their target page, if so, it will just damage their server with that amount of files. I want to be able to handle a GET request to my website, create a new page and , automatically redirect the user, and then remove the page (file).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a URL shortener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742013/how-do-i-create-a-url-shortener)

Comment: @Balastrong No. I want to be able to handle a GET request to my website, create a new page and , automatically redirect the user, and then remove the page (file).