# Decoding Arbitrary-Length Values Using a Fixed Block Size?

Tags: encoding, x86, simd, decoding, binary-data

#### Background

In the past [I've written an encoder/decoder](https://github.com/naftulikay/python-ipminify/blob/master/ABOUT.md) for converting an integer to/from a string using an arbitrary alphabet; namely this one:

```
abcdefghjkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ23456789
```

Lookalike characters are excluded, so `1`, `I`, `l`, `O`, and `0` are not present in this alphabet. This was done for user convenience and to make it easier to read and to type out a value.

As mentioned above, my previous project, [`python-ipminify`](https://github.com/naftulikay/python-ipminify) converts a 32-bit IPv4 address to a string using an alphabet similar to the above, but excluding upper-case characters. In my current undertaking, I don't have the constraint of excluding upper-case characters.

I wrote my own Python for this project using the excellent [question and answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742013/how-do-i-create-a-url-shortener) on how to build a URL-shortener.

I have published a stand-alone example of the logic [here as a Gist](https://gist.github.com/naftulikay/b16ee4d5ea943be8d0c93c2d16a875b8).

#### Problem

I'm now writing a performance-critical implementation of this in a compiled language, most likely Rust, but I'd need to port it to other languages as well.. I'm also having to accept an arbitrary-length array of bytes, rather than an arbitrary-width integer, as is the case in Python.

I suppose that as long as I use an unsigned integer and use consistent endianness, I could treat the byte array as one long arbitrary-precision unsigned integer and do division over it, though I'm not sure how performance will scale with that. I'd hope that arbitrary-precision unsigned integer libraries would try to use vector instructions where possible, but I'm not sure how this would work when the input length does not match a specific instruction length, i.e. when the input size in bits is not evenly divisible by supported instructions, e.g. 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512 bits.

I have also considered breaking up the byte array into 256-bit (32 byte) blocks and using SIMD instructions (I only need to support x86_64 on recent CPUs) directly to operate on larger unsigned integers, but I'm not exactly sure how to deal with `size % 32 != 0` blocks; I'd probably need to zero-pad, but I'm not clear on how I would know when to do this during *decoding*, i.e. when I don't know the underlying *length* of the source value, only that of the decoded value.

### Question

If I'm going the arbitrary unsigned integer width route, I'd essentially be at the mercy of the library author, which is probably fine; I'd imagine that these libraries would be fairly optimized to vectorize as much as possible.

If I try to go the block route, I'd probably zero-pad any remaining bits in the block if the input length was not divisible by the block size during encoding. However, would it even be possible to decode such a value without knowing the decoded value size?

Comment: How recent?  If you can exclude Zen 1 / Zen 2, Intel since Haswell and AMD since Zen3 have efficient BMI2 pdep / pext that could help repack bits from 5 or 6 bits per byte down to contiguous.  Unfortunately those instructions are slow on older AMD.  With `vpshufb` for lookup tables to map between integers and ASCII codes (for the low 4 bytes) that might get you somewhere...  (I'm assuming you choose your base, i.e. alphabet size, to be a power of 2 so it's just a matter of re-grouping bits, not multiplying and dividing.)

Comment: Division by non-power-of-2 is expensive; arbitrary-precision division by non-power-of-2 is *very* expensive.  If it makes any sense at all to set your alphabet size to a power of 2, by all means do it.